# Open file in program from batch file windows

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file to open a bunch of programs on demand (not start-up)

E.g.

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16"
start lync.exe
```

I want to open files inside another program automatically specifically AutoHotKey scripts but with the option to open general files e.g. something like

```
    d:
    cd "D:\.PortableApps\AutoHotkey_1.1.28.02\" 
start notifier.ahk AutoHotkeyU64.exe
```

I have tried

```
START "" /D "D:\.PortableApps\AutoHotkey_1.1.28.02\notifier.ahk" "D:\.PortableApps\AutoHotkey_1.1.28.02\AutoHotkeyU64.exe"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend, first and foremost, that you open a Command Prompt window and enter `start /?` to read its usage information.

---

For your first example, you should just `Start` your executable `linc.exe` directly, you do not need to change your working directory to do so:

```bat
@Start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\lync"
```

*In the above example you'll note that as the first doublequoted string is expected to be a title, I have used an empty one to prevent your command being read as one. Also if you cannot be sure that `.EXE` is a value entry under `%PATHEXT%`, you'd include that `.exe` extension, i.e. `@Start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\lync.exe"`.*

As a final note, as `lync.exe` is a Microsoft Office product, I'd fully expect that its path is entered in the registry under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\lync.exe`. In that case, you should not need to enter its path at all and the following would be all that is needed:

```bat
@lync
```

---

For the second example, the first thing you should note from the output of `start /?` is that you should be starting the executable with its script as an argument, not starting the script with its executing file as the argument.

If your AHk command does not require that your current directory is its own, the following should suffice:

```bat
@Start D:\.PortableApps\AutoHotkey_1.1.28.02\AutoHotkeyU64 D:\.PortableApps\AutoHotkey_1.1.28.02\notifier.ahk
```

If there were spaces or other poison characters in any of those names or paths, then the safer doublequoted option, complete with executable extension, would be better:

```bat
@Start "" "D:\.PortableApps\AutoHotkey_1.1.28.02\AutoHotkeyU64.exe" "D:\.PortableApps\AutoHotkey_1.1.28.02\notifier.ahk"
```

If you need to change directory, for the AHk command to work properly, then you have two options along the lines of your provided tests:

```bat
@PushD D:\.PortableApps\AutoHotkey_1.1.28.02 
@Start AutoHotkeyU64 notifier.ahk
@PopD
```

*If you cannot be sure that `.EXE` is a value entry under `%PATHEXT%`, you'd include that `.exe` extension, i.e. `@Start AutoHotkeyU64.exe notifier.ahk`. Also if there were spaces in the first line directory path, then you would doublequote it, if that path was not on an NTFS file system.*

To use the `Start` option directly, *similar to the first example*:

```bat
@Start /D D:\.PortableApps\AutoHotkey_1.1.28.02 D:\.PortableApps\AutoHotkey_1.1.28.02\AutoHotkeyU64 notifier.ahk
```

If there were spaces or other poison characters in any of those names or paths, then the safer doublequoted option, complete with executable extension, would be better:

```bat
@Start "" /D "D:\.PortableApps\AutoHotkey_1.1.28.02" "D:\.PortableApps\AutoHotkey_1.1.28.02\AutoHotkeyU64.exe" "notifier.ahk"
```

---

In all of the examples above I have prepended the commands with **`@`**. If your script has already turned `echo`ing off, then you can omit all of those prepending characters.

Answer (score 1):

When you run `cd /?` from `cmd` you will find this section in the help topic:

> Use the /D switch to change current drive in addition to changing current
>   directory for a drive.

You are therefore required to use the `/d` switch when `c`hanging `d`irectories which are on a different drive letters.

```
@echo off
cd /d "D:\.PortableApps\AutoHotkey_1.1.28.02\" 
start notifier.ahk AutoHotkeyU64.exe
```

Alternatively by using `pushd`

```
@echo off
pushd "D:\.PortableApps\AutoHotkey_1.1.28.02\" 
start notifier.ahk AutoHotkeyU64.exe
popd
```

Or simply `start` (without the incorrectly implemented `/D` as in your example).

```
start "" "D:\.PortableApps\AutoHotkey_1.1.28.02\notifier.ahk" "D:\.PortableApps\AutoHotkey_1.1.28.02\AutoHotkeyU64.exe"
```

Alternatively you can use `pushd`

or `start /b` without creating a new window:

```
start /b "" "D:\.PortableApps\AutoHotkey_1.1.28.02\notifier.ahk" "D:\.PortableApps\AutoHotkey_1.1.28.02\AutoHotkeyU64.exe"
```

Just as a reminder, all of the relevant help for the above mentioned commands can be found by running the following from `cmd.exe`

```
cd /?
pushd /?
popd /?
start /?
```